# How do I use 7-zip to add a folder to an archive, including only files with certain extensions?

Tags: 7-zip

I know that the 7-zip command to add a folder to an archive is, e.g.:

```
"c:\program files\7-zip\7z" a testArchive.zip c:\myFolder
```

And the command to add only files of a certain extension to an archive is, e.g.:

```
"c:\program files\7-zip\7z" a testArchive.zip c:\myFolder\*.jpg -i!c:\myFolder\*.pdf
```

How do I add a folder to an archive containing only files of a certain extension?  I tried:

```
"c:\program files\7-zip\7z" a testArchive.zip c:\myFolder\ -i!c:\myFolder\*.jpg -i!c:\myFolder\*.pdf
```

but that just added all the files in the folder, not just the .jpg and .pdf.  What's more, it also added subfolders, which I didn't want.

Is there a way to use the -x switch so that I can say, "add all files except those that are *not* these extensions, and don't add any subfolders"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command told 7z to add the data in `myFolder`, then also to add stuff in `myFolder` that was a jpg, then that which is a pdf. You can just use:

```
"c:\program files\7-zip\7z" a testArchive.zip -i!c:\myFolder\*.jpg -i!c:\myFolder\*.pdf
```

and that will pick up the correct files through the inclusion filters.